# Firebase libraries must be either above or below 14.0.0 after connecting firebase to android studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

So I was having no package found problem which I solved By authenticating and syncing firebase in android studio, after that I suddenly started having this issue when I sync gradle. Here is My file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "APP NAME"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 42
        versionName '3.7'
    }

    dexOptions {

        jumboMode true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    implementation 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    implementation 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I am unable to figure what suddenly went wrong here, I minute there is no problem,just a problem related to package name in json file/firebase sync and then when that is solved this popped up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This dependency is violating the statement made in the error message:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0
```

You should update it:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3
```

The latest versions of all the libraries are [listed here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).